# Вопросы сочетаемости

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость

Уместно ли в данном случае употреблять слово "тезисы"? Если да, то можно ли использовать это слово в сочетании с "объявлять"?
"Этот шаг по факту изменил мировое морское право и объявлял следующие тезисы:
объявление недействительной блокады там, где она существует только на бумаге и не обеспечена наличными военно-морскими силами;
свободу торговли нейтральных держав с портами враждующих государств и нейтральной каботажной торговли..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так. Первое.

> ТЕЗИС [тэ], -а; м. [греч. thesis - положение]
>   1. Лог. Утверждение, истинность которого должна быть доказана. Главный т. Короткий, основной т. Выдвинуть т. Защищать свой т.
>   2. В идеалистической философии: первая стадия всякого процесса развития.
>   3. обычно мн.: тезисы, -ов. Кратко сформулированные основные положения доклада, лекции, сообщения и т.п. Написать, составить, опубликовать
>   тезисы. Тезисы соответствуют статье.

*Большой толковый словарь Кузнецова.*
Ну никак не подходит.

Второе. У вас по сути "объявить объявление" получается. Это никуда не годится вне зависимости от всего остального.

Третье. Тезисы "по факту" не объявляют. Это понятно.

Но тут ситуация сложнее. Во-первых, само слово "объявлять" здесь неудачно. "Вызвал к жизни", пожалуй. Или ввел в мировую практику (чего? - морского права?). Во-вторых, "тезисы" действительно тоже не очень смотрится в таком сочетании. Выже не о тезисах говорите, а о каких-то опциях, возможностях, приемах, что ли... "Принципы", кстати, - тоже не то.

*Этот шаг по факту изменил мировое морское право и **ввел в практику** следующие **акции**: объявление недействительной блокады там, где она существует только на бумаге и не обеспечена наличными военно-морскими силами; свободу торговли нейтральных держав с портами враждующих государств и нейтральной каботажной торговли..."*

Насчет принципов (из другого ответа) - я бы поостерегся использовать. Надо посмотреть детально, соответствует ли это ситуации. Я не вижу в таких вещах **принципа**. Принцип - это основополагающее положение документа (закона, договора). А тут по внешнему виду речь идет лишь о каких-то правах, в лучшем случае вытекающих, например, из *"принципа реального исполнения"* - есть такой принцип в международном праве, не уверен, что здесь именно он, но явно, что какой-то задействован, сами по себе ваши положенияна принцип не тянут.

(+)

Что касается "объявить тезисы", то, естественно, в другом контексте и в другом значении вполне возможно. *В таком-то году Ленин объявил о своих "Апрельских тезисах"*. Не знаю, насколько верно исторически, но по грамматике и сочетаемости тут все нормально. Хотя здесь тоже есть варианты, лучше сказать "обнародовал".

Answer (score 0):

Естественно, "тезисы" здесь неуместны. Принципы – куда ни шло.
И почему употреблено разговорное "по факту" вместо общелитературного "фактически"?